# Angular 2 get Header Response

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I am trying to get the `Headers` of response from my Browser when accessing my **Angular2** simple app ( **ng new application** ) and I can't get it to work for some reason.

I just want to get angular to show my header data on the page .

Comment: Have you tried anything before? Put up your code, so that we can bring it forward.

Comment: I have tried to use . import { HttpModule , Response , Http } from '@angular/http';
but i cant make it work , i made dozens of versions but all wore wrong .

Comment: If you could give me a short example on how to get the header data from the module i would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I will propose you the following code:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', window.location.href.toString(), false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders().toLowerCase();
alert(headers);
// or for specific header:
var date=req.getResponseHeader("Date");
```

You can find in the variable headers your browser header.
With best regards,